# how to select first value of the grouped data and compare it in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compare the first value of x1 and x2 in the grouped (grouped by ID) dataset. If the first grouped value of  x1 is greater than the first grouped value of x2, I will assign ID as 1 otherwise 0. Let me show you this in an example. You can see my input variable below

```
dt<-data.frame(ID=c(100, 100, 101, 101, 101), x1=c(1200, 1600, 1350, 1400, 1500), 
                        x2=c(1100, 1410, 1900, 1300, 1100))
```

Since 1200 > 1100, I will assign 1 to ID 100 and since 1350 < 1900,  I will assign 0 to ID 101.
Finally, my output will be

```
res<-data.frame(ID=c(100, 101), res=c(1,0))
```

how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `aggregate(x1>x2~ID, dt, head, n=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can group by using `dplyr` and then access the first element of each group using `[1]` and then compare them using an `if_else` statement in `summarise`

```
dt %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(res = dplyr::if_else(x1[1] > x2[1], 1, 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID   res
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     1
2   101     0
```

For completeness here is a `data.table` version and a benchmark.

```
dt[, .(z = ifelse(x1[1] > x2[1], 1, 0)), by=ID]
```

```
> dt = data.table(ID = rep(100:1000, each=1000), x1 = sample(901000), x2 = sample(901000))
> 
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
... dplyr = dt %>% 
... dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
... dplyr::summarise(res = dplyr::if_else(x1[1] > x2[1], 1, 0)),
... 
... 
... data.table = dt[, .(z = ifelse(x1[1] > x2[1], 1, 0)), by=ID]
... )
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
      dplyr 39.167330 42.806415 46.91723 44.422384 46.28869 125.31500   100
 data.table  9.497764  9.844758 10.94920  9.930658 10.53419  22.87746   100
```

So if time is of the essence, then the `data.table` version is ~4x faster.

Comment: No need of `ifelse` just do `z = +(x1[1] > x2[1])`

Comment: True, but (for me at least) the if_else statement makes the code a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution. I hope I got what you have in mind right:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(res = ifelse(first(x1) > first(x2), 1, 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID   res
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     1
2   101     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(res = +(first(x1) > first(x2)))
```